# Can I read a DVD as a single file on windows?

Tags: c

I know it's possible on linux. I tried using `open("E:", 0);` and `open("E:\\", 0);` but it returns as -1. I'd like to read the DVD as a large file rather than use it as a filesystem.

Comment: You can by reading from `\\.\PhysicalDriveN` where `N` is the number of the device, not sure how to fetch that number though, just pointing you a direction.

Comment: @Havenard: Hmm. Do you happen to know a USB drive path? It may be easier to test with

Comment: @Havenard: That's for fixed disks, and opens the whole disk including partitions. A DVD isn't partitioned.

Comment: @acidzombie24: Do you want the raw bits? Because any optical disk is full of metadata such ass error correction, and usually you don't get that part.

Answer (score 1):

There's plenty of information on the `CreateFile` documentation on MSDN. It's fairly simple, though: "When opening a volume or removable media drive (for example, a floppy disk drive or flash memory thumb drive), the `lpFileName` string should be the following form: **`\\.\X:`**. Do not use a trailing backslash `\`, which indicates the root directory of a drive.

Comment: I haven't looked into it deeply but when I tried [this code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363147(v=vs.85).aspx) everything ran fine. I added ReadFileEx refering to this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/bb540534(v=vs.85).aspx I get the error code 5 which is permission denied. I held down ctrl+shift as I launched MSVC (UAC/Admin) and still got the same error